# Find values from a Word table in an Excel table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, compare

I want to iterate through the values of a column in a table in a word file, and check if those values are in a column in a table in an Excel file. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub CompararColumnas_Click()

   Dim wrdTbl As Table
    'Set your table
    With ActiveDocument
        If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count >= 1 Then
            Set wrdTbl = .Tables(InputBox("Table # to copy? There are " & .Tables.Count & " tables to choose from."))
        End If
    End With

    Dim AD_UsersPath As String
    AD_UsersPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Comparar Columnas VBA\Animales.xlsx"
    Dim AD_USERS As Object
    Set AD_USERS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    AD_USERS.Visible = False
    AD_USERS.Application.Workbooks.Open AD_UsersPath
    
    LastRow = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells.Count
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 1 To LastRow
        wVal = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(I, 1)
        User = AD_USERS.Cells(AD_USERS.Range("A:A").Find(What:=wVal).Row, 1).Text
        wrdTbl.Cell(I, 2).Range.Text = User
    Next I

End Sub
```

This code iterates in `wVal` the values from the first column in a table from Word and after that it goes to Excel to find those values in the first column of the Excel table. If it finds them, it copies the values in the second column of the word table. However, it gives me an error 91. If instead of `Find(What:=wVal)` I put something like `Find(What:="Word")` it does not give me an error and puts the word "Word" in every cell of the second column of the word table. How can I solve this?

Comment: FYI you are using two different tables - `ThisDocument.Tables(1)` and `wrdTbl`

Comment: You're right, it is what happens when I recycle my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cell values in Word have a two-character "end of cell" marker (Chr(13) + Chr(7)) which you need to remove:

```
Private Sub CompararColumnas_Click()

   Dim wrdTbl As Table
    'Set your table
    With ActiveDocument
        If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count > 1 Then
            Set wrdTbl = .Tables(InputBox("Table # to copy? There are " & _
                                  .Tables.Count & " tables to choose from."))
        Else
            Set wrdTbl = .Tables(1) 'default to the only table
        End If
    End With

    Dim AD_UsersPath As String, wb As Object, ws As Object
    AD_UsersPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & _
                   "\Desktop\Comparar Columnas VBA\Animales.xlsx"
    Dim AD_USERS As Object
    Set AD_USERS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    AD_USERS.Visible = False
    Set wb = AD_USERS.Workbooks.Open(AD_UsersPath)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim LastRow As Long, I As Long, User
    LastRow = wrdTbl.Columns(1).Cells.Count
    
    For I = 1 To LastRow
        wVal = TwrdTbl.Cell(I, 1)
        Left(wVal, Len(wVal)-2) 'strip off "end of cell" marker
        User = ws.Cells(ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=wVal).Row, 1).Text
        wrdTbl.Cell(I, 2).Range.Text = User
    Next I

    wb.Close False
    AD_USERS.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for! :)